# How to solve the Helmholtz equation in damped oscillator BCs?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, computational-physics, simulations

Given the surface of the vibrating object $\partial \Omega$, I am trying to simulate its outer sound pressure field $p(x)$ by the `equivalent source method`.[1]

For the `Helmholtz` equation
$$
(\nabla^2 + k^2) p = 0
$$

I can solve it in harmonic BCs, but **how to solve it in damped harmonic BCs**?

## 1. Harmnoic oscillator case

> It is easy to solve

Consider position $\mathrm x \in \mathcal \partial \Omega \subset R^3$, If it is a harmonic oscialltor, whose acceleration $\mathrm a(t; \mathrm x)$ are:
$$
\mathrm a(t) = \vec d e^{i w t}
$$
then the Neumann BCs of Helmholtz can be easily got:
$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial \mathrm n} = - \rho \mathrm a(t) \cdot \mathrm n
$$
where $\mathrm n$ is the outer normal of the vibrating surface.

I can then use the `Equivalent source method`[1] to solve it.

The `Equivalent source method`[1] is nothing more than finding a linear combination of basis functions (monopoles) to fit the BCs.

In this case, If I *solve the question at the start, I can use it forever, because the amplitude of BCs is not changed.* The solution will be a constant, undamped sound pressure field.

## 2. Damped oscillator case (question)

But, if the boundary vibration is damping (which is the common sense, nothing is vibrating forever in daily life, but just tuning for a while), the boundary acceleration $\mathrm a(t)$ become a *damped harmonic oscillator*.
$$
a(t) = \vec d e^{- \xi t} e^{i w t}
$$
where $\xi $ is a damped factor (determined by the internal friction or viscosity of this object).

How can I use the equivalent source method in this case? If I solve it at one moment $t$, then at next time $t + \Delta t$, the boundary conditions are damped, It seems I need to resolve it, really costly.

## reference

[1] Kondapalli, P.S., Shippy, D.J. and Fairweather, G., 1992. Analysis of acoustic scattering in fluids and solids by the method of fundamental solutions. The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America, 91(4), pp.1844-1854.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: Replace $\omega$ with $\omega-i\xi$.

**Longer Answer**:

The Helmholtz equation is derived from the wave equation, which may be written as
$$\nabla^2P -\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial t^2} = 0,$$
where $P$ is the time-domain acoustic pressure and $c$ is the wave speed.  There are two approaches to obtaining the Helmholtz equation from this equation.  The first is to take the Fourier transform, but the other is to assume a particular form of the solution.  To demonstrate the second approach, we assume that the acoustic pressure takes the form $P=pe^{-i\omega t},$ and substitute this into the wave equation, yielding the Helmholtz equation
$$\nabla^2p + \frac{\omega^2}{c^2}p = 0.$$
Usually this approach is taken when there is a driving force of some sort that has the time dependence assumed.

Following this logic, if the source condition has a time dependence that may be written as
$$e^{-i\omega t}e^{-\xi t}=e^{-i(\omega-i\xi)t}=e^{-i\tilde\omega t},$$
where $\tilde\omega\equiv\omega-i\xi$, then we would assume that we may write
$$P=pe^{-i\tilde\omega t}.$$
Substitution into the wave equation would then yield the Helmholtz equation
$$\nabla^2p + \frac{\tilde\omega^2}{c^2}p = 0.$$
Thus, the only difference between dealing with a system with a harmonic source condition and a decaying harmonic source condition is the use of $\tilde\omega$ versus the use of $\omega$.

Your post is sufficiently vague that I cannot provide too many details on a specific case.  I will assume that you would be able to solve your system with a time-harmonic  source, and denote the solution as $p=p(\vec x,k)$, where $k=\omega/c$.  Then, the solution to the case of a decaying time-harmonic source would simply be $p=p(\vec x,\tilde k)$, where $\tilde k=\tilde\omega/c=(\omega -i\xi)/c$.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear expression which may cause misleading. But your answer is exactly what I want. Would you please point out which place I can clarify, and then I can accept your answer?

Comment: Mostly I was just saying that I can't give you a solution, because there isn't a complete problem.  For example, you could say that you are looking at a long tube with a source at one end; this would allow you to give an explicit solution.  Your question is fine as is.